# Own cache DNS server

Tags: c#, python, caching, dns

I need to write an own cache DNS server in Python (or C#, Java). It must receive requests, get the answer recursively and save all information from answer (every resource note) to the cache. 
Does anyone has anything like this? 
Usually I write in C# and prefer it, but can't find in it anth that will help me with this task. So I suppose Python is better for it, but I've never used it before. 
Will be glad if you help me :)

Comment: Where are you currently stuck? Also, this type of project can be completed equally well in Python, C# and Java, all of those languages have the required functionality. Simply chose the language you are most comfortable with.

Comment: I don't understand how to get all resource notes for saving them to the cache, not only ip, that client wants to know

Comment: Did you try doing http://bit.ly/1HPP2l6?

Comment: @OK12 you need to read RFC 1034, RFC 1035, RFC 1123, RFC 2181, RFC 2308, RFC 5966, RFC 6891.  And probably many others too.

Comment: I wrote a DNS Server from scratch a while back that might be a useful start for your project - handles recursive queries by pass-thru to host's default DNS config.  Take a look here: https://github.com/stephbu/csharp-dns-server

All pass-thru action happens here: https://github.com/stephbu/csharp-dns-server/blob/master/Dns/DnsServer.cs#59